# Automatic Tracing (not tracking) of polygons in QField

Tags: polygon, digitizing, qfield, tracing

[image]

Does QField support the Auto-Tracing Tool like QGIS does? Like shown in the picture above.

I tried to export my QGIS projects with the activated Auto-Tracing tool, but in QField the tool doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

The Plugins you use in QGIS do not get transfered into QField. There is no tracing in QField.